# Why MainActivity is Freezing even if i am using AsyncTask?

Tags: android

I am Recording Framelayout using AsyncTask for a certain amount of time. (suppose 5 seconds)

The code is working fine but it's making my activity freeze.

```
 private class AsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
            try {
                framlayout.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(framlayout.getDrawingCache());

                    // collecting bitmaps and at the end making video

                }
                framlayout.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
}
```

**There is no issue with the code for creating video**

**My issue is activity is freezing even if I am using Asynctask**

Please help

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please show how you start your async task.

Answer (score 0):

this line do its job in UI thread, as `framlayout` (probably) belongs to some `Activity` or `Fragment`

```
framlayout.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
```

I'm surprised that this doesn't throw "wrong non-UI thread" exception, but on the other hand it doesn't change any param of this `View`...

`setDrawingCacheEnabled` itself makes `View` generate bitmap (save/store some byte-array) with own look, this is heavy and may provide some small freeze

if you need this print screen keep drawing cache enabled from start, don't toggle this on runtime (from UI or any other thread)

Comment: I try setDrawingCacheEnabled true from the beginning but still gives the same result.

Answer (score 0):

use this code and manage your loop inside it

```
  var exec = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1)
  var check = 0
  exec!!.scheduleAtFixedRate({

      if (check < 5) {
        Bitmap bitmap =Bitmap.createBitmap(framlayout.getDrawingCache());
            }

      check++

    }, 0, 100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
```